# Using a for loop to print dictionary items once without repeating the print function for each item listed

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, printing

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow in general, so sorry if my formatting sucks. But I created this dictionary and assigned it keys and values contained inside of lists. Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
favorite_languages = {
   'jen': ['python', 'ruby'],
   'sarah': ['c'],
   'edward': ['ruby', 'go'],
   'phil': ['python', 'haskell'],
}


for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():
   for language in languages:
        if len(languages) >= 2:
            print("\n" + name.title() + "'s favorite languages are:" +
                  language.title())
        elif len(languages) == 1:
            print(name.title() + "'s favorite language is: " +
                  language.title())
```

The result of the code when ran comes out looking like this:

```
Sarah's favorite language is: C
Edward's favorite languages are:Ruby
Edward's favorite languages are:Go
Jen's favorite languages are:Python
Jen's favorite languages are:Ruby
Phil's favorite languages are:Python
Phil's favorite languages are:Haskell
```

But I only want it to repeat the sentence once for each key, while containing the corresponding values within each sentence. Like this:

```
Sarah's favorite language is: C
Edward's favorite languages are:Ruby, Go
Jen's favorite languages are:Python, Ruby
Phil's favorite languages are:Python, Haskell
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to iterate over languages in loop. [string.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) should be used here:

```
for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():
    be = ' is: ' if len(languages) == 1 else 's are: '
    print(name.title() + '\'s favorite language' + be + ', '.join(languages))
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. What does that '.join' thing do if I may ask? I haven't worked with that before.

Comment: The `join` command 'joins' the string it used on together with the argument that is given to it.
So, in this case, it joins the string `', '` together with the strings that are in `languages` and returns it as a single string.

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like

```
for name, languages in favorite_languages.items():
     print("{}'s favorite language{} : {}".format(
             name.title(),
             "s are" if len(languages) > 1  else " is",
             ", ".join(languages))
     )
```